# React - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

### So I'm having an error message - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
       5 | import products from '../products'
       6 | 
       7 | function ProductScreen({ match }) {
       8 |     const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id)
       9 |     return (
      10 |         <div>
      11 |             {product.name}
```

This is my ProductScreen.js file where is causing an issue

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products'

function ProductScreen({ match }) {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id)
    return (
        <div>
            {product.name}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

and my App.js

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen/>} exact />
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen/>} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also tried to change match.params.id to Number or ParseInt (match.params) and still gave me an error...

I know this is very simple but I'm stuck here and cannot go further... Any help would be appreciated!

One more question - Inside App.js, where Route is, in the tutorial was using components={} attribute instead of element={}. And when I tried the same it gave me an error, so I had to fix it another way. Do you know why it caused an error?

From the tutorial

```
<Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
```

My fix --

```
<Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen/>} exact />
```

Answer (score 23):

The tutorial appears to be older and using `react-router-dom` version 5 whereas you are using version 6. In version 6 there were many breaking API changes. The `Route` components no longer use `component` or `render` props, the `element` prop that is passed a valid JSX literal replaced them. [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (`history`, `location`, and `match`) also no longer exist, the routed components *must* use the React hooks to access them now.

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Given route: `<Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen/>} />`

Use the `useParams` hook to access the `id` match param. The match param will be a string, so if your product ids are a number type, then to ensure strict equality convert the `_id` property to a string to use a type-safe comparison. Don't forget that `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` if no match is found, so the code should check the result value prior to attempting to access into it for properties when rendering.

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function ProductScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((p) => String(p._id) === id);

  if (!product) return null; // or fallback UI

  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Reese When using Number(id) it didn't work for me. without that, it's working.

Comment: @FazleRabbiAdor Seems like your id values are strings (*as they probably should be*) and not of type `Number`. It all depends on your data properties and their types. The route params will ***always*** be a string by default though, so sometimes conversion is necessary for strict equality (`===`) checks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, finally, this code worked.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { id } = useParams();

const product = products.find((p) => p._id === (id));

 <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    ...
    
    function ProductScreen() {
      const { id } = useParams();
      const product = products.find((p) => p._id === id);
      return <div>{product.name}</div>;
    }
    
    export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function ProductScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === Number(id));
  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This solved :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been marked solved but I'm doing this course on Udemy as well.

Here is my working solution in case someone needs help on this course. I used params as useParams()

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import products from "../products";

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === params.id);
  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Glad you answered this 12 hours before I ran into the same issue in (probably) the same course. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For router 6 use this

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SingleProduct = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const product = products.find(product => product._id === (id));
}
```

(id) without Number(id) or it will undefined

```
<div className='single-image'>
  <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
</div>
```

and add this in App.js

```
<Route path='/products/:id' element={<SingleProduct />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**In App.js file:** 

<Route path="/products/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />

**In SingleProduct.js file:** 

import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const SingleProduct = () => {

const { id } = useParams()
const product = products.find((p) => p._id === (id))

 <div>
      <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
      <h3>product.name</h3>
</div>
}
export default SingleProduct;


**This code worked in my case.**
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Router:

```
<Route path='/product/:id' element={ProductScreen} />
```

In the ProductScreen component:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
...
const { id } = useParams();
```

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful for you. In this case

```
function ProductScreen() {
  const[product,setProduct]=useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchProduct(){
         const {data}= await axios.get('/api/products/'+id)
         setProduct(data)
     }
     fetchProduct()
 },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
const ProductView = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === params.id);
}
```

Dont' for get to import useParams in react-router-dom!

Answer (score 0):

I think in **react-router-dom@5.1.0** vesrion it support the componant but in eairleir version react change policy and in **react-router-dom@6.0.1** or more version componant is replaced by element.

But Now, You use react-router-dom@6.0.1 or highier version.

**<Route path='/' element={} exact />**

Answer (score -1):

import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

const { id } = useParams();
const product = products.find((p) => p._id === (id));

In app.js
<Route path="/product/:id" element={} >

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).