# Private route and reading Params - React + Django

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, frontend

I am building a Django + React app following a tutorial where they use react-router v5, and I use the v6.2.1 (code is here : https://github.com/linkedweb/realest_estate/blob/main/src/containers/ListingDetail.js).

I want to have a PrivateRoute for authenticated user rendering details of a product. I tried to adapt the code, according to this post especially ([React - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290770/react-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-params)), but I cannot make it work and I get:

***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')"***

I tried many variants, but this is what I believe to be the closest to the right way :

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Layout >
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          ...
          <Route exact path='/listings' element={<Listings/>} />
          <Route path='/listings/:id' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path='' element= {<ListingDetail />}/>
          </Route> 
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> 
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>)
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ auth: {isAuthenticated, loading }, ...rest  }) => {
    return (!isAuthenticated && !loading) ? (<Navigate to='/login' />) : (<Outlet {...rest}/>)}
    
PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**Listing Details**

```
const ListingDetail = (props) => {
    const [listing, setListing] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const slug = props.match.params.id;

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}};

        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/listings/${slug}`, config)
        .then(res => {
            setListing(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => { }); });

    return (
        <div className='listingdetail'>
            <p>{listing.title}</p>
        </div>
    );};

export default ListingDetail;
```

I tried to change 'const slug = props.match.params.id;' to 'const { slug } = useParams();', even outside the useEffect, but it didn't work !

What can I do in order to retrieve the data about the product and display them ?

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `path` prop to the `Route` you are trying to render that you want the routed component to access a route param of (*`slug`*).

```
<Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
  <Route
    path='/listings/:slug'
    element= {<ListingDetail />}
  />
</Route>
```

`ListingDetail` should use the `useParams` hook to retrieve the `slug` route param. Access the `slug` route param *outside* the `useEffect` hook and add `slug` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

```
const ListingDetail = () => {
  const { slug } = usePrams();
  const [listing, setListing] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      },
    };

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/listings/${slug}`, config)
      .then(res => {
        setListing(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => { });
  }, [slug]);

  return (
    <div className='listingdetail'>
      <p>{listing.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! I got a 404 error as the {slug} was undefined, but changing the url to path='/listings/:slug' solved it !

Comment: @Guillaume-ds Oops, quite right. Sorry for any confusion that may've caused, but it sounds like you caught my error and corrected.